# Does service bus have Task bases API

Tags: azure, servicebus

I just want to know, does service bus support async programming.
Can I use Async/Await in service bus?
How should I do that?
Does there any samples for that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The beta of sdk 2.0 has this, see http://nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus/2.0.0-beta for the bits, and check http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/04/11/task-based-apis-for-service-bus.aspx for example of api usage

Answer (score 0):

I think most of the Azure client libraries (SDK) do have support for asyncronous calls. In fact, this is the suggested way of using them. For example, the QueueClient type (part of ServiceBus cliend SDK) has a bunch of `Begin*`, `End*` methods. You may find the [list of all methods here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queueclient_methods.aspx).

However these signatures are using the pattern with IAsyncResult, which is different from the Async/Await pattern.

So to answer your question more correctly: No, the current version of ServiceBus does not support task based async processing. It does however support IAsyncResult based asynchronous processing.